# Find all files in dir/subdirs and save into an array but also rename files with spaces to underscore

Tags: bash

I'm able to find all files in a directory and its subdirectories. I save it into an array but I also need to rename ones that have spaces in their names to an underscore.

## Sample structure

```
./abc 123.txt
./dags/ftp.pyc
./dags/ftp.py
./logs/scheduler/2017-05-12/ftp.py.log
```

## Find the files and insert into array

```
array=($(find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0))

# Does not work
for i in ${array[@]};do echo ${i// /_};done

#Output
./abc
123.txt
./dags/ftp.pyc
./dags/ftp.py
./logs/scheduler/2017-05-12/ftp.py.log
```

It would be more ideal if I could run regex against the value before it goes into the array.

Comment: `echo "filename with spaces" | tr ' ' '_'` >  `filename_with_spaces`

Comment: You have not succesfully entered the filenames into an array.  The first element in the array is "./abc", and the second is "123.txt".

Comment: Just use rename, or do something like:

   `find . -exec sh -c 'echo "$0" "${0// /_}"' {} \;`

(this doesn't handle whitespace other than space)

Trying to cram the files into an array is doomed to fail.

Comment: There is no need to create an array. You can directly loop through the results of `find`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with the above command is that the array is looping through the filename with space as two variables and not one.
Something like below should work

```
find . -type f -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' file; do echo ${file// /_} ; done
```

Comment: THANK YOU. this is what i was looking for.